# How to learn electronic keyboard to support voice lessons

Tags: piano, voice

I'm almost 53. I'm taking voice lessons as a beginner and I love the idea that I can improve my voice and enjoy singing. I asked my voice teacher if she thought I would benefit from playing an instrument as well and she said yes. She recommended the piano (electronic keyboard) as the note placement is linear (hope I'm making sense) and I don't have to deal with getting the notes to sound right as I would with a string or wood instrument. My voice teacher refers to herself as a "piano hack" and doesn't have any advice on how I might learn to play the keyboard.

I'm taking two hour-long voice lessons a week and I don't want to commit to regular piano lessons. And, I have no desire to excel at piano. I want to be able to play notes, sequences, scales, and someday some songs to help me to hear notes and match pitch. I was a math major in college so I have no doubt that I can learn the music theory I need from a book, course or website.

Given my story and goals how would you recommend I learn piano? I've read cautions on the web about the importance of piano lessons but my interest in learning to play is fairly limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different levels of "learning piano".

Truly learning piano will take a solid hour out of EVERY day of your life.  At minimum.  And will be helped along CONSIDERABLY by piano lessons from a piano teacher that you "click" with.

That's a lot of time and effort that will probably WAY overshadow your voice lessons and practice.

So I'd say "dink around" on piano.  No teacher, watch some videos, buy a digital piano (88 weighted keys or it's a toy).  and just play really easy melodies really slowly.  Sound out some simple melodies in your ear - NO CHORDS (unless you want to start diving in).

A word of warning - you may find piano is way cooler than singing.  And, in any case, they complement each other perfectly.

Jump in!  But stay in the shallow end :)  ...FOR NOW

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Would you say more on how piano and singing can complement one another? How can I use a piano (keyboard) to accelerate my voice work?

Comment: iiiiii'm an ok singer, but never studied it.  the singing, I just wing.  it's trickier to go the other way round cuz piano is a pretty deep instrument.  voice is wayyy more expressive with it's different timbre capabilities and smoothly variable pitch.  But a piano can do bass, chords, melody, even a good stab at percussion.  But maybe nevermind what I said about melody.  Learn the C, F, and G chords.  Find simple pop that uses em.  Play the chord, sing the melody on top.  chords change slowly so it's pretty doable.  Good luck :)

Comment: I agree that an hour a day is a good amount to learn an instrument but I don't agree that that's a lot of time to take away from other things. If one watches zero TV shows then perhaps an hour is a lot, but it's only about 6% of waking hours.

Comment: aaaare you a working parent with aging parents of your own?  cuz that 6% of your life can be mighty precious when your responsibilities get "up there" in life.